# How to target CSS in contact form 7 for error message?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

can you help with targeting CSS for contact form 7 message error for my site: http://www.lisaweng.com/contact/

[the yellow background for the message error is what I'm referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVmvf.png)

also trying to find the right CSS class for it so I can change the font family as well..

When inspecting it, it says the class is wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-validation-errors

so I put in the custom CSS in my wordpress as: 
`.wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-validation-errors {
background-color: #cfcce6;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
}`

and it didn't target it..

umm if you need to see the message just type for example one letter in one of the fields in the contact form and that message will show up for reference

Need help, thanks so much..

can you tell me the right class for that error message box so I can style the CSS? I want to change it's background color and font family.

Please help thank you so much <3

<3

Comment: try only `.wpcf7-response-output{
background-color: #cfcce6;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
}`

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I tried it, the font worked!! It changed to Source Sans Pro, thank you so so much!! I'm trying to figure out how to change background color as it's currently still the same color lol

Comment: Fixed!! Found this line which I just tried when inspecting: .div.wpcf7-response-output.wpcf7-validation-errors { and it worked!! The background color and font family are now changed. Might have missed that one before. Thank you so much for helping =))!!! <3 <3